# SeekBar doesn't correct show progressDrawable

Tags: android, xml, seekbar

Sorry for my english. I tried to use a custom SeekBar, but its SeekBar doesn't correctly show progressDrawable. Image one is my progress:

[image]

If I have a large value, progressDrawable looks like this

[image]

My **xml**

```
 <SeekBar
                                android:id="@+id/seekBarHome"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                                android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/thumbler_small"
                                android:max="50"
                                android:thumb="@mipmap/men"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**thumbler_small**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_background"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seek_bar_progress" />
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the parent layout that contains your `SeekBar` isn't wide enough to accommodate the custom drawable width. Try making sure the parent layout is wider than the `SeekBar` by at least the diameter of your custom drawable on both sides. Also, make sure you aren't limiting it's width with margins or padding, but rather center it in the parent layout in a way to leave extra space on the sides to display your drawable fully. Easiest way is to set `SeekBar`s width to be less then that of it's parent by at the diameter of your drawable and see if it'll resolve your issue.